# How to save drop-down list choice upon update using PHP/HTML?

Tags: php, html

I want to create a drop down list that allows the user to choose a value that is pulled from a database. When the page is updated based on the chosen value, the choice is reverted to the "original," default choice. How can I allow the selected value to save and remain when the page is updated?

```
// Drop Down Menu to choose Session

if (isset($_POST['action']))
{
    $action = $_POST['action'];
    $session = $_POST['session'];
}
else
{
    $action = "";

    if (!isset($_POST['session']))
    {
        $session = "";
    }
    else
    {
        $session = $_POST['session'];
    }
}

?>

<form name='update' action='emailinquiry_webinarnew.php' method='POST'>
Session: 
<select name='session'>
    <?php

    $query = "SELECT distinct session FROM web_attendees";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        echo "<option>".$row['session']."</option>";
    }
    ?>
</select>
<input type='submit' name="ViewButton" value='View'/>

</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))  {
    if($row['session']==$session){
        echo "<option selected='selected' >".$row['session']."</option>";
    } else {
        echo "<option >".$row['session']."</option>";
    }
}
```

hope it will work for you fine...

Answer (score 0):

Just add such condition in the while loop that prints the options to add the `selected="selected"` that will select the option by default:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $selected = '';
    if (isset($_POST['session']) && $row['session'] == $_POST['session'])
        $selected = ' selected="selected"';

    echo "<option{$selected}>".$row['session']."</option>";
}
```

Comment: Still reverts to default value :/